# Search and replace string of certain length using Perl regex

Tags: regex, perl, replace

I am trying to search and replace a string that is up to and including 3 characters in length with nothing (so 'deleting' the element contents).

So I have something like:

```
foreach (@array) {
   s/^{1,3}$//;
}
```

E.g.

```
@array = ('one', 'two', 'three', 'four', 'five', 'six', 'seven');
```

So when printing, expected output would be:

```
result:  result:  result: three  result: four  result: five  result:  result: seven
```

So for the affected inputs, the output would be an 'empty place'.

This at the moment doesn't happen... I'm betting I'm making a simple mistake due to my still-shaky understanding of regex. Any help appreciated!

If there is a simple way to actually remove the element totally without creating a new array, that would also be useful to know.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Simple regex problem aside, you can use `grep` to select the elements you want:

```
@array = grep { !/^.{1,3}$/ } @array;
```

Then just print the results:

```
print "Result: $_\n" foreach @array;
```

Results:

```
Result: three
Result: four
Result: five
Result: seven
```

Comment: oh this is good! It would make things a lot easier to remove the actual elements in this way, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

If you want to match any three characters, `s/^.{1,3}$//` should work. I just added a dot after the `^`, as your original regex didn't specify what kind of character you wanted to match 1-3 of.

Comment: also didn't affect it :/
I want words of exactly three characters or less to be removed, but not from the longer words.

Comment: it doesnt matter about the characters themselves - I remove numbers earlier on.

Comment: That's strange. The ^ and $ should ensure that it doesn't replace longer words.

Comment: got it working now! I don't know exactly what changed but I'm accepting that it works... thanks to both answers, both correct but other just first :)

Answer (score 4):

Probably  `s/^\w{1,3}$//;`

You are forgetting `\w` to group it with `{1,3}`

Comment: whatever changed to make it work also works with this. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The way I read your question is that you want to actually modify the array's contents.  You could use [splice](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/splice.html) thusly:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;
use Data::Dumper;
my @array = qw(one two three four five six seven);
my $i = 0;
for (@array) {
    m/^\w{1,3}$/ && splice(@array, $i, 1, undef);
    $i++;
}
print Dumper \@array;
print "\n";
for my $e (@array) {
    print defined $e ? "result: $e  " : "result:  "
}
print "\n";
```

And when run:

```
$VAR1 = [
          undef,
          undef,
          'three',
          'four',
          'five',
          undef,
          'seven'
        ];

result:  result:  result: three  result: four  result: five  result:  result: seven
```